# How to properly construct a long command line with a mix of single and double quotes?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line-interface

I've got a long list of commands strung together (aws cli, jq, cut, sed) that works for me with which I'm trying to now run within a bash script. I'm having problems with the single and double quotes.

If I ran this manually it would be the following:

```
aws \
  --profile app-prod \
  --region us-east-1 ec2 describe-instances \
  --filter 'Name=tag:ChefRole,Values=foo_bar' \
           'Name=instance-state-name,Values=running' \
| jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | [.InstanceId, .Tags[].Value] | @csv' \
| cut -d ',' -f1 \
| sort > sort.out;sed 's/"//g' sort.out
```

In my script I'm trying to pass in parameters the `region` and `Values`
I've tried this:

```
awsCLI(){
    cmd=$(aws --profile app-prod --region ${region} ec2 describe-instances --filter 'Name=tag:ChefRole,Values='${component}'| jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | [.InstanceId, .Tags[].Value] | @csv' | cut -d ',' -f1 | sort > "${_sorted}";sed 's/"//g' "${_sorted}")
}
```

Placing in the variable - `cmd=$(commands here)` has worked for me before in other scripts, but not this time.

I also tried just running as is:

```
aws --profile app-prod --region ${region} ec2 describe-instances --filter 'Name=tag:ChefRole,Values='${component}'| jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | [.InstanceId, .Tags[].Value] | @csv' | cut -d ',' -f1 | sort > "${_sorted}";sed 's/"//g' ${_sorted}"
```

Either of these didn't work for me. Please advise on best practice for this. Should I break this out? How would you build this long command?

Thanks you.

*(Editor's note: first code block split by `\` and indented; A.T.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was actually trying to eliminate the eternally long horizontal scroll bars from your question, but then decided to convert it into an answer, maybe it actually solves your problem (if not, just tell, will delete):

```
awsCLI(){
  cmd=$(aws \
    --profile tealium-prod \
    --region "${region}" ec2 describe-instances \
    --filter 'Name=tag:ChefRole,Values='"${component}" \
  | jq -r '.Reservations[].Instances[] | [.InstanceId, .Tags[].Value] | @csv' \
  | cut -d ',' -f1 \
  | sort > "${_sorted}" \
  ; sed 's/"//g' "${_sorted}" \
  )
}
```

I think the main problem was superfluous single tick around `Values='"${component}"`. In general you can concatenate strings by juxtaposition, all you have to remember is that `""` expand the variables, whereas `''` do not.

The root cause was non-existent indentation. Look up what the backslash in the end of the line does, it will make your life much easier.

Comment: @noober I'm not sure what you want to do with variable `cmd` though. Maybe you want to enclose the entire `$(...)` into additional double quotes `"$(...)"`.

Comment: thank you! that works for me. I used your example in your answer. I didn't have to enclose in double quotes.

Comment: @noober Good. Maybe one additional remark: the indentation style with `;` at the beginning of the line is not the only one possible, and it is not exactly "classical", but rather haskell-inspired. You might want to choose another indentation style that is closer to languages that you use, or to languages used in your organization. Not everyone might immediately recognize the whole beauty of lines starting with `,` and `;`. But that's definitely better than cramming everything into a single line. If you have longer `Name=tag,Values=blah`-sections, consider constructing them as separate vars.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the ability to use Python, the boto3 library is very easy to use. The issue with multiple types of quotation marks becomes moot.